# Device in fastboot mode not recognized at all as USB device

Tags: usb, fastboot, lg

My LG G5 does not get recognized as an USB Device at all when it is connected to the PC in fastboot mode.

While it is recognized just fine as an adb device, after rebooting into fastboot mode via
`adb reboot bootloader` it is not recognized as an USB Device in Windows (The device manager does not show any device with wrong drivers and does not react to replugging the device). I also tried it on a different machine with the same results.

Ubuntu also does not recognize the device at all, `lsusb` does not output the device anywhere. It also does get recognized as an adb device when booted up normally.

I installed the necessary (I tried LG and Google) drivers and tried different USB ports (2.0 and 3.0) and cables. The phone just is not noticed as an usb device at all when in fastboot mode.

Could this be due to a broken usb port? Which seems odd because the phone is recognized when not in fastboot mode.

What else could cause this weird behaviour?

Thank You

Comment: fastboot disabled from LG?